# Apache Solr - wrong count words in termfreq function

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Is any solution, to use termfreq to pharse, not one word(in one word work correct), in pharse like: termfreq(field,"test value") - work fail:

schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="text_books_index" class="solr.TextField">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.MorfologikFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" />
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.MorfologikFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: did not the question clearly...Could you please elaborate more on the question?

Comment: Yes, example: In doc, in field text there is a sentence: "This is an example sentence", if termfreq(text,"example") = 1 - it's correct, but if termfreq(text,"example sentence") = 0, it's fail

Comment: I would suggest try with ShingleFilterFactory in your field type..

Comment: I try, but not working :(

Comment: try it in the index analyser only...also why are you using the edgengramfilter....if you are looking phrase match...you should not be using it

Answer (score 1):

So, new schema.xml field type:

```
<fieldType name="text_books_index" class="solr.TextField">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.MorfologikFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="4"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.MorfologikFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

and field declarate:

```
<field name="bookIndex" type="text_books_index" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
```

and query:

```
{
"responseHeader": {
"zkConnected": true,
"status": 0,
"QTime": 1,
"params": {
"q": "bookIndex:\"search phraze\"~3 ",
"fl": "id,termfreq(bookIndex,\"search phraze\"),termfreq(title,\"search phraze\"),termfreq(author,\"search phraze\"),termfreq(isbn,\"search phraze\"),termfreq(notes,\"search phraze\"),termfreq(tableOfContent,\"search phraze\"),termfreq(descriptionBook,\"search phraze\")",
"start": "0",
"sort": "",
"fq": "",
"rows": "10"
}
},
"response": {
"numFound": 1,
"start": 0,
"docs": [
{
"id": "000",
"termfreq(bookIndex,\"search phraze\")": 0,
"termfreq(title,\"search phraze\")": 0,
"termfreq(author,\"search phraze\")": 0,
"termfreq(isbn,\"search phraze\")": 0,
"termfreq(notes,\"search phraze\")": 0,
"termfreq(tableOfContent,\"search phraze\")": 0,
"termfreq(descriptionBook,\"search phraze\")": 0
}
]
}
}
```

And not working :(

Comment: Please add these details to your question and not as an answer - and take a look at what the output when indexing the content under "Analysis" is - it'll tell you which tokens are being generated. Also, remember to reindex your content after changing the field types.